# Help limiting inner join

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join

I need help limiting inner join.

**Tables:**

---

**users:**

- uid
- left
- active

---

**files:**

- fid

---

**uid=fid**

---

```
SELECT uid
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN files AS x ON u.uid = x.fid
WHERE u.left = '0'
AND u.active = '1'
ORDER BY `u`.`uid` ASC
```

**result:**

```
uid
3
3
3
3
7
47
47
47
47
47
47
47
47
47
47
```

**I need to limit INNER JOIN to 5 . so "uid" will not show up more than 5 times. like:**

```
uid
3
3
3
3
7
47
47
47
47
47
```

---

**update:**

Here is the php code

```
 $res = do_sqlquery("SELECT uid FROM users as u INNER JOIN files as x ON u.fid=x.fid WHERE u.left = '0'  AND u.active='1'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
   {
       while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
       {
       $x=$arr["uid"];
       quickQuery("UPDATE users SET pots = pots+".$GLOBALS["bui"]."*".$cleaint."/900 WHERE id = '$x'");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

A MySQL only solution, without using PHP

```
SELECT uid
from (
    SELECT u.uid, @r:= if(@u=u.uid,@r+1,1) r, @u:=u.uid
    FROM users AS u
    CROSS JOIN (select @u:=null) g
    INNER JOIN files AS x ON u.uid = x.fid
    WHERE u.`left` = '0'
    AND u.active = '1'
    ORDER BY u.uid ASC
) U
WHERE U.r <= 5
ORDER BY uid ASC
```

or more generally, just SQL without MySQL variables

```
SELECT u.uid
from (
    SELECT u.uid, count(*) C
    FROM users AS u
    INNER JOIN files AS x ON u.uid = x.fid
    WHERE u.`left` = '0'
    AND u.active = '1'
    GROUP BY u.uid
) U inner join (
   select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3
    union all select 4 union all select 5) V ON U.C>=V.n
ORDER BY U.uid ASC
```

Comment: thank you but didn't work. the result is not right. I edited my post and added the php

Comment: I just test you code on my localhost and "A MySQL only solution" the result is not right."just SQL without MySQL variables" works great on my localhost Server version: 5.1.37 but on my site Server version: 5.0.91-community-log I get error #1054 - Unknown column 'u.uid' in 'field list'

Comment: @user that version could be case sensitive. Change the first line to uppercase `SELECT U.uid`. Otherwise, have you changed any table/alias names at all between your local host and site server?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`uid`, ":", MAX(5, COUNT(`fid`))) `uid_count`
FROM ...
GROUP BY `uid`
```

Gives you results like:

```
uid_count
3:4
7:1
47:5
```

In PHP, for example, you can then split after fetching:

```
while (FALSE !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))) {
    ($uid, $count) = split(':', $row['uid_count'], 2);
}
```

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz MySQL client